# What color is the button bezel on Qui-Gon Jinn's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, the-phantom-menace

I've recently purchased a replica hilt for Qui-Gon Jinn's lightsaber and it comes with both a black and a silver button bezel.

Looking at various stills from *The Phantom Menace* it appears that the prop uses the black bezel throughout the film. However, photographs of Liam Neeson with a gifted prop and pictures of the *Galaxy's Edge* version of the saber show it with the silver bezel.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm assuming that out of universe it's simply because many props were made for various reasons and the details might not be consistent.

Is there a canon answer as to what color is correct or should I simply pick the one that I like best?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the '*hero*'* lightsaber wielded by Neeson in *The Phantom Menace* and [sold at auction by Propstore](https://propstoreauction.com/lot-details/index/catalog/318/lot/95208). The bezel under the activation button is grey/silver.

[image]

Neeson appears to have a second copy of this prop mounted on his plaque. Given its near-perfect condition, it may not actually be a '*screen-used*' version.

---

A '*stunt*'* version of the lightsaber was also used in the film and [sold by Propstore](https://propstoreauction.com/lot-details/index/catalog/138/lot/28598/) for a lower price. The bezel is black rubber.

[image]

*<sub>[**Hero props**](https://www.anatomorphex.com/props-sets) are *"props used in close-up shots and must be highly finished and free of defects"* / **Stunt props** *"require the same detail as hero props but must be created out of soft, safe materials that are also tough enough to remain intact as actors interact with them"*</sub>